# If a Python package is just a module, can that module import from sister modules and expose their functions?

Tags: python, package

Suppose I have a package structured like:

```
root
+-- package_as_a_module.py
+-- setup.py
+-- requirements.py
```

In my case, `package_as_a_module.py` has grown much larger than initially anticipated, and it's becoming difficult to manage. Is it possible to add a new module to the root directory, say `utils.py`:

```
# utils.py
def func_a()
  return "Hi!"
```

and then expose the functions of `utils.py` via an import statement into `package_as_a_module.py` like:

```
# package_as_a_module.py
from utils import func_a
```

So that after installation, I can use `from package_as_a_module import func_a`?

I attempted this without success, [here](https://github.com/jeffrey-cochran/multi-module-import-test). The modules from which the main module imports are not recognized, and the import fails. I suspect this might be possible with a true package structure, maybe in the **init**.py file or something. I'll give that a whirl next.

If no one proposes an alternative, I'll answer my own question in the negative.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @st.ph.n I won't have a chance to until this evening when I get home. If no one answers before then, I'll answer my own question.

Comment: I was just going along the lines of PoC, that you should show that you tried it, it failed, and now you're looking for help. In theory, it should work, but would rely on other dependencies of the module.

Comment: @st.ph.n My attempt didn't work. You can see the project structure on a public github repo I created for the purpose, [here](https://github.com/jeffrey-cochran/multi-module-import-test)

Answer (score 0):

You can.

In your file `main_module.py` you did not call the `print_all()` function, that is why nothing happened.

```
from module_a import print_hello_world as phw_a
from module_a import print_hello as ph
from module_b import print_hello_world as phw_b


def print_all():
    ph()
    phw_a()
    phw_b()

print_all()  # You need to call a function for it to do something
```

Comment: It's not that it didn't do anything, the imports failed. I'm using `pip install THIS_REPO` to get the package, and then trying to import the `print_all` function. When I do that, I get an error along the lines of 'module_a not found.' Are you saying that if I just add a function call to the module, this error will go away, and it will recognize the imports?